# TypeScript type inference in a higher order function based on input of returned function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to create a generic "pipe" function that accepts a series of map functions that transform an input and eventually returns the output of the final map function. I started with a basic function that only accepts one map function as a parameter:

```
const pipe = <T, U>(map: (input: T) => U) => (initial: T): U => map(initial);
```

However, when I try and use it with an identity function, I get `unknown` back:

```
// test is unknown
const test = pipe(i => i)(1);
```

Ideally, `test` should be `number` in this example.

My hypothesis here is that `pipe(i => i)` is evaluated as `pipe(unknown => unknown)`, and this doesn't get updated with any inference from the returned function. When I call `pipe(unknown => unknown)(1)`, it's fine passing a number into a function that accepts `unknown`, but because that function also returns `unknown`, that's what eventually gets returned.

I'm wondering if my hypothesis here is correct, and if so, whether there's any activity regarding it somewhere in the TypeScript dev scene.

Is there any way in TypeScript currently to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Inference with curried function calls only flows from left to right. So you can just switch around the order and start by passing the initial value as demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9nqJm). Would this answer your question?

Comment: How, specifically, do [none of the previous answers to questions about piping functions](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+pipe+function) not answer your question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - it looks like most of these questions are either about chaining functions or about creating a `pipe` like operator similiar to RxJS. This question seems to be more about currying. I remember similar questions like this but could not find one yet.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasS., I thought as much. I was hoping there'd be a way to have (T => U) => T => U to make composing multiple pipes together easier, e.g. pipe(pipe(i => i + 1))(1) rather than pipe(num => pipe(i => i + 1)(num))(1), but there doesn't seem to be an ergonomic way to do that

Answer (score 2):

Your indentity function tries to infer type from caller, and your pipe function tries to infer type from callback, making the type `unknown`.

You should define type on either `pipe` or `i=>i`, or make `i=>i` generic

```
const pipe = <T, U>(map: (input: T) => U) => (initial: T): U => map(initial);

const test0 = pipe(<T, >(i: T) => i)(0) // 0
const test1 = pipe<number, number>(i => i)(0) // number
const test2 = pipe((i: number) => i)(0) // number
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the function (i) => i - the input type (i) is unknown.

The fix would be to say what the input type is:

Typescript playground: [link description](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgSzgUxgXhgHgCoBoYCqAfABQC2AhnAFwwkJhwCuUt2AlOkYZ2t-WARQEFADZt2tAlxiU4AoSNHsA3ACgNagPRaYUZNBgIIMJmADWYEAHcwa0JFj7DGRChL1aYJmQBGyACdebgR2EgBGVSA)

```js
const test = pipe((i: number) => i)(1);
```

The only way to have multiple pipes, in which input is the output of the other is to create a building. Like this:

```js
type PipeFunction<Input, Output> = (input: Input) => Output;

class PipeBuilder<FirstInput,LastInput,LastOutput> {
    constructor(private pipes: Array<(input: any) => any>) {}

    public static of<Input, Output>(fn: PipeFunction<Input, Output>): PipeBuilder<Input, Input, Output> {
        return new PipeBuilder([fn]);
    }

    public pipe<Output>(fn: PipeFunction<LastOutput, Output>): PipeBuilder<FirstInput, LastOutput, Output> {
        return new PipeBuilder([ ...this.pipes, fn ]);
    }

    public build(): PipeFunction<FirstInput, LastOutput> {
        return (firstInput: FirstInput): LastOutput => {
            let result = this.pipes[0](firstInput);
            for(let i = 1; i <= this.pipes.length; i++) {
                result = this.pipes[i](result);
            }
            return result as any as LastOutput;
        } 
    }
}
```

Then we can use and chain the pipes like this:

Full demo with builder [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACglpAYgVwHYGNhwPaoDwCSqYywANFAPKknAB8UAvFABRzGkBcURtAlEwbVgtANwAocegA2AQwDO82AggAhZHGkATCACc8iOLvnBepMgBkFpjuSsnhtBgG9xUd1HS4Tu5Jmy6LGC6cABussDQYCry3ACCurqyIHhsttyyqCACjAyZIHQCzgC%20kh5QJABG0nDoUCYRtVDYAGaEthSOpHQsLajc8EhomDj4ZuRUNN18Ayrqmjr64xTLkyLdUK7l5boQwMi6qFCoEADuypDz2nosANp9ALp8EuWlbh5VNXXRkHhd9L1%20hcICgMFhcHh7MB-p0pvQZsCrosDEYTKsoTC1k5Nu9tlBdvtDsczoiNNdArcoAA6GnAAAWcHkVJ%20EHkFD6UCeLw8b3KnyalTJWhYCMGIOG4PwhmMNloFAxcJcuO2BIOR16qNlXCg0rRtgRCvWwEEOLxeOke3xrOQ0mNzHpjOZMVuAAYHhqZeNnsqzVAWgEWBbjXAmFAAIyiKAhvBQB1MllMi2oADm9MjcAA1Bmij7fR5dvIbXbYwz4864O6C0XvXmebm8aqiVXbVAFK2sq2lIaxPWoMUoMrSm8pN5jSykXpQ2KJ7plVTWiwWKhkABbbjLleVPQ5BgbqnAbAAZWAIRTIr4c5Zi58O4qsmMECIwBYN4v5SdkCXq5NJ3OABEIggFgACYXWA4CyDDSCKA3Pg3w8D8gK0QCTQAIgAFTpaBkMiKNYigVCoAzdwcIgfdsAIQ9KGPU9k3PCRJC8VATCgFdAJCWQagALwgLRQRGXBQ3HIU9CpQUFhFCQmJY5tizYyIOO43j%20MlFgAFZvWk7ALSpaRsDo2TniAA)

```
const pipeBuilder = PipeBuilder
    .of((num: number) => num.toString())
    .pipe((str) => parseInt(str))
    .pipe(num => new Date(2022,1,1, num))
    .pipe(date => "The date is: " +  date.toISOString());


const materializedFunction = pipeBuilder.build();
const result = materializedFunction(5);
console.log(result);
```